# How can run a Python script from an Fsharp module

Tags: python, f#

While writing a fsharp module I realized the need to make a call to a python script.
- Cannot switch my fsharp module to python it'll break established infrastructure
- Cannot move the python functionality to fsharp, as it wouldn't be possible to convert all the nuances/efficiency of the code.

Any recommendations on how to call a python script from a fsharp module, passing in a couple of parameters (string values) and getting back a string value response?

Comment: Since F# runs on the .NET runtime, have you looked at using IronPython which does the same?

Comment: A quick and dirty way would be to just run the Python script as separate process through System.Diagnostics.Process and capture the output of that.

Comment: You can also try pythonnet

Answer (score 3):

Try out the Nuget package Python for .NET.  The Nuget link is here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/pythonnet/2.3.0-py35-dotnet and includes links to the project on github.

Comment: also pythonnet has reference to 2 wiki articles for F# usage: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki

Comment: heya, thanks for responding! haven't logged into here in a minute and ended up working around it with a fsharp script translation of the python script

Comment: @user6500904 Good call.  You are going to get your best performance by doing that.